# Using input time in Blazor server side has strange behavior

Tags: blazor-server-side

Out side an EditForm I want to use a input type="time" as the following code shows:

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="sTime" @bind="@StartTime">
```

the Bound Property should be a DateTime variable otherwise it does not allow, As this code shows:

```
 DateTime StartTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
 private async Task AddingVisit()
 {
     ...
     VisitStart = startDate.Date + TimeSpan.Parse(StartTime.ToShortTimeString());
     ... 
 }
```

But when the code in the method reaches to the point that uses StartTime property, It jumps out from code to HTML and begins doing some works and then does not come back to execute the remaining code, Why this happens and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, Removing TimeSpan.Parse Solved the problem:

```
DateTime VisitStart = startDate.Date + StartTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
```

The execution now is normal, and does not jump to Html.